# Access Spring Boot Actuator build.version property with @Value

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

THis should be easy, but doesn't work.
I have spring-boot-actuator activated in my Spring Boot (2.0.1-RELEASE) application.

The Actuator-Endpoint `/actuator/info` works as expected and also shows the correct version info. The file `build-info.properties` is present.

When trying to access the version property with (e.g. in my Spring-Controller-Class):

```
@Value("${build.version}) private String version;
```

The action fails with the error `Could not resolve placeholder 'build.version' in value "${build.version}"`.

ANy suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With spring expression language it is pretty simple and clean.

```
@Value("#{buildProperties.get('version')}")           // not 'build.version'
private String myAppBuildVersion;
```

Or better, `Autowire` the `buildProperties` bean directly to your components so you can play with it as you want.

```
@Autowired
private BuildProperties buildProperties;
```

> NOTE: The `autoconfiguration` strips off the `build.` prefix. So your
>   `SpEL` expressions should use `version` as key. Not `build.version`.

Comment: Thanks! This is the way to go and works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to add the file `build-info.properties` as `@PropertSource`

```
@SpringBootApplication()
@PropertySource("classpath:META-INF/build-info.properties")
public class MyApp implements WebMvcConfigurer { 
  [...]
}
```

Then you can use the build-info in annotations

```
@SomeAnnotation(value = "${build.version}")
public class someClass { ... }
```

Answer (score -1):

In your @Service, put the @Value in the constructor, as a parameter of the constructor. Don't use a standalone value and try to reference it.

like this:

```
@Service
public class myService {

  public myService(@Value("${my.param}") String myParam) {
   client.withParam(myParam).build();
  }

}
```

Where your application.properties has a value like:

```
my.param=http://google.com
```

I have tried other implementations and they do not work. for example,

```
 @Service
 public class myService {

      @Value("${my.param}")
      String myParam;

      public myService() {
       client.withParam(myParam).build();
      }

  }
```

Does not work.

In this case, the service will be initialized, but the string will be null. I can't explain it. Something to do with param construction and bean initialization timing, I guess.